# Slide block element OUT when hovering

Tags: java, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a image with a info box layered over it, with the css posted below.

The normal thing would be to have this appear when hovering over the image, however, I want the opposite. I want the box to slide out/down about -50px when hovering the image. Anybody got a tip for this?

```
.imgTitleInfoTop {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 370px;
}
```

Comment: [This might be helpful.](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2011/04/19/pure-css-slideout-interface/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but this is kind of the opposite of what im trying to do. I have a box on top of my image the entire time, and i want is to slide out when i hover it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want the .imgTitleInfoTop element to hide when you hover an image, so the code should look like this then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.yourImage').hover(function() {
  $(.imgTitleInfoTop).animate({
   height: 0
  }, 300);
 }, function() {
  $(.imgTitleInfoTop).animate({
   height: '60px'
  }, 300);
 });
</script>
```

(300 is the time in miliseconds, how much this action takes, so you can make it faster or slower)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this (using Jquery)?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.imgTitleInfoTop').hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
   height: 0
  }, 300);
 }, function() {
  $(this).animate({
   height: '60px'
  }, 300);
 });
</script>
```